# Not able to retrieve value in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in android to save the user information and retrieving it.
I am getting the value from firebase database but its not casting to my POJO class

**UserInformation.java**

```
public class UserInformation {
private String phoneNo;
private String address;


public UserInformation() {
}

public UserInformation(String address, String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
 }
}
```

ValueEventListener

```
 public ValueEventListener displayUserData() {
    return new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                UserInformation userInformation = 
                dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                mEtAddress.setText(userInformation.getAddress());
                mEtPhoneNo.setText(userInformation.getPhoneNo());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
}
```

[image]

The data snapshot is not casting to UserInformation.class. I am getting all null values in it.

Comment: Have you tried adding setters to the POJO?

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you attach your listener?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attaching your listener one level above the `UserInformation` node in the JSON tree. In that case the result contains a snapshot with a *list of* snapshots. Even if there is only one snapshot, your code needs to handle the fact that it's a list.

```
public ValueEventListener displayUserData() {
    return new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserInformation userInformation = 
                userSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                mEtAddress.setText(userInformation.getAddress());
                mEtPhoneNo.setText(userInformation.getPhoneNo());
            }
        }
```